# Install software from audio assault on ubuntu studio 20.04.1 LTS

Tags: sound, software-installation, permissions, vst

I'm trying to install an audio plugin from audio assault software for Linux, however I can't create a folder on /opt folder, I can't attach anything to the /opt folder as well, these are the instructions provided to install this software:

copy the "ReAmp R1 Data" folder to "/opt/Audio Assault/"
e.g. "/opt/Audio Assault/ReAmp R1 Data/"

ReAmp Studio R1.so goes wherever you put your vst plug-ins

ReAmp Studio R1 Standalone is the standalone binary

don't forget to set reading and writing permission for the data folder, and execute permissions for the stand alone.

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Firstly if your system is upgraded it wouldn't report as 20.04.1 (*that would imply you're more than 18 months behind on security fixes as 20.04.2 was released [here](https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2021/02/05/ubuntu-20-04-2-lts-released/) but installed systems now show as 20.04.4 or 20.04.5*) but even then `/opt` requires elevated privileges, did you elevate privileges as required to write there?

Comment: My apologies you're right, i'm using the mos recent ubuntu studio version 22.04 (KDE plasma version 5.24.4. I'm new in linux so I was reading all regarding on how to elevate privileges to make changes to root folders but I have not success, I tried using the console with the command kdesudo dolphin (nothing happens), gksudo dolphin (nothing happen again), gfsudo (same problem).... so a little help there will be good than you.